# In Linux, simulate slow traffic incoming traffic to port e.g. 54000

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

is there a way in Linux to simulate slow traffic inbound to my server at a specific port? I looked at NETEM but it only seems to WAN wide.

Comment: I've been meaning to figure this out for a while; it's more complicated than you may think, but [it is possible](http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm). Off to dinner.

Comment: can't **telnet host port**  be used?

Comment: @sarnold, you shouldn't need to add a htb queue, see below

Comment: For Reference: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196730/simulate-network-latency-on-specific-port-using-tc

Answer (score 5):

An example of limiting all traffic matching tcp (protocol 6) destination port of 54000 at 256Kbits inbound to `eth0`, using `tc`...

As root...

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 50 u32 \
    match ip  protocol 6 0xff \
    match ip dport 54000 0xffff police rate 256kbit burst 10k drop \
    flowid :1
```

You can monitor it like this... notice the `dropped` number for `ffff`, below

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ sudo tc -s qdisc show
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 17796311917 bytes 5850423 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc ingress ffff: dev eth0 parent ffff:fff1 ----------------
 Sent 140590 bytes 1613 pkt (dropped 214, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth1 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

To delete all ingress traffic filters:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress
```

Comment: tks for the reply, will try first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Can I replace "police rate 256kbit burst 10k drop" with "delay 100ms" and this would delay incoming traffic by 100ms?

Comment: This is superb, far simpler than the route I _thought_ was necessary to take. Thanks Mike!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but no, you can't drop in "delay 100ms" in place of "police...".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Depending on what type of traffic you need, it may already provide the functionality.